# Linq to Entities error when comparing int? to a values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to write a recursive function that will traverse a tree.  I have my entity 'Folder' with two properties of ParentFolderID and FolderID.  If the folder is at root level, then its ParentFolderID is null.  I created a recursive function that accepts a paramater ID and adds returns all the folder entities with the same ParentFolderID as ID, but I'm getting the error of 'Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'.

Here is my function:

```
    private List<Folder> GetFolderChildren(int? folderId)
    {
        var childFolders = new List<Folder>();

        //  finalList is List<> that is actually returned
        var finalList = new List<Folder>();

        //  Your looking at the root level folder
        if (folderId == null)
        {
            childFolders = DocumentEntities.Folders.Where(x => x.ParentFolderID.Equals(folderId)).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            childFolders = DocumentEntities.Folders.Where(x => x.ParentFolderID == folderId).ToList();
        }

        //  If there are no childFolders, then you've hit the bottom of this branch.  Return this folder.
        if (!childFolders.Any())
        {
            finalList.Add(DocumentEntities.Folders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.FolderID == folderId));
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var childFolder in childFolders)
            {
                finalList.AddRange(GetFolderChildren(childFolder.FolderID, pageName));
            }

            //  Now that you've gone through this folders children, add this folder
            finalList.Add(DocumentEntities.Folders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.FolderID == folderId));
        }

        return finalList;
    }
```

It never reaches the foreach when the folderID is null nor when its an int.  Any ideas?

Comment: You should remove the redundant `catch` clause.

Comment: I agree with you @YuvalItzchakov, I was putting it there to see what error was thrown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `x.ParentFolderID` is `null`, you will not get access in the `Equals` method because it is null. Try to compare the entire value with the argument since it has the same type, for sample

```
childFolders = Entities.Folders.Where(x => x.ParentFolderID == folderId).ToList();
```

Comment: But if the search starts where the ParentFolderID will be null, it appears this will prevent you from starting 'at the root level'?

Comment: Yes, you are right @Jason. If it star from the root level, I edited my anwser :). Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Ok @FelipeOriani, I have figured out my answer (with your help).  Can I post what worked yet still mark yours as the 'right' answer?

Comment: Yes, you could improve my anwser :). It can help other users too.